# Delphi android google play services version

Tags: android, delphi, service

I create a Delphi app with RAD Studio 10.4.

I added a TMapView, to use it I have create an API account with Google and set the apiKey in [Project > Option > Application > Information version] for all the target (Android debug/release 32/64 bits).

It's work well in Debug mode, but when I compile to Release I have the following error :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your
> app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist. You must have the following
> declaration within the  element:

I didn't find any clear answer to solve it, I had the same problem in Debug when the apiKey wasn't set.

When I check my AndroidManifest I don't see this line.

Comment: You can add custom elements to [`AndroidManifest.xml`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Android_Application_Manifest_File_(AndroidManifest.xml)), see [Customizing Your AndroidManifest.xml File](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preparing_an_Android_Application_for_Deployment#Customizing_Your_AndroidManifest.xml_File)

Comment: You need to select the Maps option in the Entitlements section of the Project Options

Comment: I dont really like to modify the manifest without know why the node is isnt here. Thanks you Dave ! I checked it in debug and not in release mode.